# PHP: Echoing date via german array causes error

Tags: php, arrays, date, echo

So I´ve got this array, containing the german equivilant word for each month number (without leading zero):

```
$months= array(1=>"Januar",
               2=>"Februar",
               3=>"M&auml;rz",
               4=>"April",
               5=>"Mai",
               6=>"Juni",
               7=>"Juli",
               8=>"August",
               9=>"September",
               10=>"Oktober",
               11=>"November",
               12=>"Dezember");
```

Now I´m fetching the month 3 days ago:

```
$german = date("n", strtotime("-3 days"));
```

Echoing the value of $german in $months produces an error:

```
echo $month($german);
```

Error Message:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in X on line X
```

Echoing `$german` alone doesn´t produce an error.
Echoing `$months(date("n", strtotime("some $row value from database")))` doesn´t produce an error.
What´s the problem?
I already tried doing this: `echo $months((int)$german)`, but this didn´t work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$months` is an array, not an function. When referencing an element in an array, you have to use `[]` and not `()` (which is used for calling a function or method).

```
echo $month[$german];
```

should work, while `$month($german)` tries to call a function stored in the variable `$month`.

Answer (score 2):

In your associative array, you need to surround the keys with quotes.

**Example:**

```
$months = array("1" => "Januar",
                "2" => "Februar",
                "3" => "M&auml;rz",
                "4" => "April",
                "5" => "Mai",
                "6" => "Juni",
                "7" => "Juli",
                "8" => "August",
                "9" => "September",
                "10" => "Oktober",
                "11" => "November",
                "12" => "Dezember");
```

---

**Further Thoughts:**

Since your keys are numbers, you could forgo an associative array and simply use an indexed array:

```
$months = array("Neujahr",
                "Januar",
                "Februar",
                "M&auml;rz",
                "April",
                "Mai",
                "Juni",
                "Juli",
                "August",
                "September",
                "Oktober",
                "November",
                "Dezember");
```

From this indexed array:

- `array_search("Oktober", $months)` gives `10`.
- `$months[6]` gives `"Juni"`

Comment: Both solutions don´t work for me :( They cause the same error. Should I change something with `echo $months(date("n", strtotime("-3 days")));`?

Comment: This answer does not address the issue exposed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> echo $month($german);

There are two problems with this piece of code.

The minor one is the variable `$month` doesn't exist, the array that contains the German names of months is named `$months`. There is a hint about this problem in the error message too. It says *"Function name must be a string"*. It is not a string, it is undefined.

This problem could be easily caught if you enable reporting all the errors, warnings and notices the interpreter reports when it runs the code. Check your `php.ini` and make sure the `error_reporting` line reads:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Having this set, the line `echo $month($german);` reports the notice as *"Notice: Undefined variable: month in file X on line Y"* before the *"Function name must be string"* fatal error.

The second error is the invocation of `$months()` as a function when it is not a function but an array. The correct usage is:

```
echo $months[$german];
```